# Android Manifest Editor (Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse

Something seems to have happened to my development environment.  All of the drop downs in the manifest editor have changed to "Browse" buttons that open up a "Resouce Chooser" window.

For example:

If I open the manifest editor and switch to the Permissions tab, when I add a "Uses Permission" the right panel displays a Browse button next to the Name field rather than a drop down that lists all of the available permissions.

Can anyone tell me what happened or how to switch it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies.  Just found this:

http://androidbook.blogspot.com/

Apparently it was an update to the Android Development Tools.  (Seems like a crappy update)

Comment: This is the specific link "Someone Else" is referring to: http://goo.gl/THOzq
In ADT 9.0.0 for Eclipse, this issue is no longer present, though.